# Fixing the Tic-Tac-Toe Game in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was preparing a Tic-Tac-Toe Game in tkinter, as in my code, but there is a problem . In my algorithm, there are statements which allow printing X or 0 only once on the same box, but it gets printed repatedly in many cases. Also, the `win_check()` function is not working properly (at the end of the game, when it should print 'You Win!' or 'You Lose!' or 'Draw', it doesn't print).
Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root_3t = Tk()
root_3t.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root_3t.config(bg='black')

Button(root_3t, text='EXIT', bg='red', fg='black', command=root_3t.destroy, font='Elephant 12').pack(anchor=SE, side=BOTTOM)

def game(event):
    text = event.widget.cget('text')
    coordinate = int(text)
  
    positions = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    win = None
    places = [canvas1, canvas2, canvas3, canvas4, canvas5, canvas6, canvas7, canvas8, canvas9]
    row_1 = [9,9,9] ; row_2 = [9,9,9] ; row_3 = [9,9,9]
   
    def win_check():
        global win
        if row_1[0] == row_1[1] == row_1[2] :
            if row_1[0] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[0] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_2[0] == row_2[1] == row_2[2] :
            if row_2[0] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_2[0] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_3[0] == row_3[1] == row_3[2] :
            if row_3[0] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_3[0] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_1[0] == row_2[0] == row_3[0] :
            if row_1[0] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[0] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_1[1] == row_2[1] == row_3[1] :
            if row_1[1] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[1] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_1[2] == row_2[2] == row_3[2] :
            if row_1[2] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[2] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_1[0] == row_2[1] == row_3[2] :
            if row_1[0] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[0] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
        elif row_1[2] == row_2[1] == row_3[0] :
            if row_1[2] == 1:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)
                win = True
            elif row_1[2] == 0:
                Label(root_3t, text='You Win !', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)                
                win = False
    
    boxes = 9

    Label(places[coordinate], text='X', font='CASTELLAR 48 bold').place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
    if 0<=coordinate<3 :
        row_1[coordinate] = 1
    elif 3<=coordinate<6 :
        row_2[coordinate-3] = 1
    elif 6<=coordinate<9 :
        row_3[coordinate-6] = 1
    boxes -= 1
    positions.remove(coordinate)

    win_check()

    if boxes == 0 and win == None:
        Label(root_3t, text='Draw', bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.85)

    bot_choice = random.choice(positions)
    Label(places[bot_choice], text='0', font='CASTELLAR 48 bold').place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
    if 0<=bot_choice<3 :
        row_1[bot_choice] = 0
    elif 3<=bot_choice<6 :
        row_2[bot_choice-3] = 0
    elif 6<=bot_choice<9 :
        row_3[bot_choice-6] = 0
    boxes -= 1
    positions.remove(bot_choice)

    win_check()

heading_frame = Canvas(root_3t, bg='black', borderwidth=5, relief=FLAT, highlightbackground='silver', height=100)
heading_frame.pack(fill=X)

button_frame = Canvas(root_3t, bg='grey', highlightbackground='silver', borderwidth=2)
button_frame.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.85, width=200, height=100)

main_screen = Canvas(root_3t)

canvas1 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas1.place(x=0,y=0,height=130,width=200)    
canvas2 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas2.place(x=200,y=0,height=130,width=200)    
canvas3 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas3.place(x=400,y=0,height=130,width=200)    
canvas4 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas4.place(x=0,y=130,height=130,width=200)    
canvas5 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas5.place(x=200,y=130,height=130,width=200)    
canvas6 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas6.place(x=400,y=130,height=130,width=200)    
canvas7 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas7.place(x=0,y=260,height=130,width=200)    
canvas8 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas8.place(x=200,y=260,height=130,width=200)    
canvas9 = Canvas(main_screen, borderwidth=2, highlightbackground='black', relief=FLAT)
canvas9.place(x=400,y=260,height=130,width=200)

main_screen.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, width=600, height=390)

increase = 0

for b in range(0,3):
    button = Button(button_frame, text=f"{b}", width=6)
    button.place(relx=0.06+increase*2, rely=0.1)
    button.bind('<Button-1>', game)

    button = Button(button_frame, text=f"{b+3}", width=6)
    button.place(relx=0.06+increase*2, rely=0.38)
    button.bind('<Button-1>', game)

    button = Button(button_frame, text=f"{b+6}", width=6)
    button.place(relx=0.06+increase*2, rely=0.66)
    button.bind('<Button-1>', game)

    increase += 0.15

root_3t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

board = {} # will keep board values and buttons

def update_board(clear=False):
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if clear: board[(row,col)]["value"] = ""
            board[(row,col)]["button"]["text"] = board[(row,col)]["value"]

def enable_board(state):
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            board[(row,col)]["button"]["state"] = "normal" if state else "disabled"

def new_game():
    update_board(clear=True)
    enable_board(True)
    status_text["text"] = "Your move"

def make_move(row, col, who):  # returns True if game is finished
    board[(row,col)]["value"] = who
    update_board()
    if win_check(who):
        status_text["text"] = f"You {'Win' if who == 'X' else 'Loose'} !"
        enable_board(False)
        return True
    if all(board[(row,col)]["value"] for row in range(3) for col in range(3)):
        status_text["text"] = "Draw"
        enable_board(False)
        return True
    return False

def ai_move():
    positions = [(row,col) for row in range(3) for col in range(3) if not board[(row,col)]["value"]]
    for pos in positions:
        for who in "XO":
            board[pos]["value"] = who
            win = win_check(who)
            board[pos]["value"] = ""
            if win:
                return pos

    return random.choice(positions)

def win_check(who):
    win  = all(board[(i,  i)]["value"] == who for i in range(3))
    win |= all(board[(i,2-i)]["value"] == who for i in range(3))
    for i in range(3):
        win |= all(board[(i,col)]["value"] == who for col in range(3))
        win |= all(board[(row,i)]["value"] == who for row in range(3))
    return win

def game(row, col):
    if board[(row,col)]["value"]:  # already occupied
        return
    if make_move(row, col, "X"):
        return

    make_move(*ai_move(), "O")

def resize_board(event):
    main_screen["width"] = main_screen.winfo_height()

root_3t = Tk()
root_3t.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")
#root_3t.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root_3t.config(bg='black')

heading_frame = Frame(root_3t, bg='black', highlightthickness=3, highlightbackground='silver', height=100)
heading_frame.pack(fill=X)
status_text = Label(heading_frame, text="Your move", bg='black', fg='white', font='Baskerville 16')
status_text.pack(anchor="center")

bottom_frame = Frame(root_3t, bg='black')
bottom_frame.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)
Button(bottom_frame, text='NEW GAME', bg='green', fg='black', command=new_game, font='Elephant 12').pack(side=LEFT)
Button(bottom_frame, text='EXIT', bg='red', fg='black', command=root_3t.destroy, font='Elephant 12').pack(side=RIGHT)

main_screen = Frame(root_3t, bg='black', width=420, height=420)
main_screen.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
main_screen.columnconfigure(tuple(range(3)), minsize=140, weight=1, uniform="board")
main_screen.rowconfigure(tuple(range(3)), minsize=140, weight=1, uniform="board")
main_screen.bind("<Configure>", resize_board)
main_screen.grid_propagate(False)

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        board[(row,col)] = {"value":"", "button":Button(main_screen, border=0, font='CASTELLAR 48 bold', command=lambda r=row, c=col: game(r, c))}
        board[(row,col)]["button"].grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="news", padx=5, pady=5)

root_3t.mainloop()
```

[image: -]

Comment: Thanks , I actually got my error ( quite a silly one it was -- just to keep few values off the function ) . Yours certainly looks attractive .

Comment: Can you please tell me how you've got such a beautiful GUI window -- have you updated tkinter ?

Comment: @user17593696 Nothing special. It's standard tkinter under Windows 7.